# Set bool property default value to true if the property is not passed in API call

Tags: c#, api

I am making a PUT call to update user using url https://myWebsite.com/users with json body

```
[{
"Name" : "John",
}]
```

As I have not passed the "Status" attribute in json body, it is set as false by default as false is the default value of the Boolean data type.

But, I need to set it to true as the default value if the property is not passed in the json when making the API call.

I tried to use **OnDeserializing** attribute as below:

```
   [OnDeserializing]
    void BeforeDeserialization(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        this.Status = true;
    }
```

but it was not working.

Model looks like below:

```
[DataContract (Namespace = "mynamespace")]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Please check the user model in the UPDATED question

Answer (score 2):

If you deserialize to a class, then in that class have a bool member that defaults to a true value. For instance:

```
public class NameAndStatus
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public bool status { get; set; } = true;  // default value of true
}
```

If `status` is passed in with the json body, the member will be set to that passed in value. Otherwise you will get the default value, which is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to use [DefaultValueAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign default value to boolean property `Status` like,

```
[DataContract (Namespace = "mynamespace")]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Status { get; set; } = true; 
                                    //^^^^^^^^ Set default value to Status property
}
```

In this way even if you pass value of `Status` property then default value will be replaced with actual value otherwise it will set value of `Status` to `true`.